# Can I redirect all URLs on my site to home page? Forcing users to passthrough log in rather than linking directly to pages

Tags: redirect, passwords, velo

I am very new to this world, and I'm building a project in Wix (I'm aware its not popular among more advanced people than I). I have a single password page set as my domain home (not user based), but if someone has a direct link to another page on the site then they can by-pass the security stage.

I need to be able to set all external page requests to direct to the home page, and then once inside the site be able to move freely between pages. Any suggestions would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 1):

You can either password protect any of your site pages or use members-only pages, either of these are part of Wix's existing capabilities.
You can learn more in these articles:

1. https://support.wix.com/en/article/wix-editor-password-protecting-a-specific-page-of-your-site
2. https://support.wix.com/en/article/wix-editor-creating-members-only-pages

Comment: Thanks, I've used both of these features before. The trick is I've been asked for a single password for the whole site so need to work out a way of funnelling all traffic through the home page with the password.